# Health check with VMs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine

I have this question

You need to create an autoscaling managed instance group for an HTTPS web application. You want to make sure that unhealthy VMs are recreated. What should you do?

A. Create a health check on port 443 and use that when creating the Managed Instance Group.

B. Select Multi-Zone instead of Single-Zone when creating the Managed Instance Group.

C. In the Instance Template, add the label ‘health-check’.

D. In the Instance Template, add a startup script that sends a heartbeat to the metadata server.

Which is the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to create an autoscaling managed instance group for an HTTPS
>   web application. You want to make sure that unhealthy VMs are
>   recreated. What should you do?

Let's analyze each possible answer to determine the best answer. There are two types of health checks, one for load balancers and the second for auto-healing. My comments below are for auto-healing.

This question is sort of a trick question. Depending on how you "read" the question, the answer can be different.

> A. Create a health check on port 443 and use that when creating the
>   Managed Instance Group.

This is a possible answer. You can detect the health of an instance on port 443 if HTTPS is running on the instances. However, this is not the normal case. Usually, SSL offload is performed at the load balancer with backend traffic being HTTP. However, the question states "HTTPS web application". This is a key point. In order to have auto-healing, you must have or create a health check and apply it to the Managed Instance Group.

> B. Select Multi-Zone instead of Single-Zone when creating the Managed
>   Instance Group.

This is a possible answer. If all of your instances are running in a single zone, the loss of a zone means the loss of all instances. In this case, auto-healing will not work. Using a multi-zone architecture adds zone fault tolerance. However, the loss of a zone does not mean new instances will be created in the other zones unless you also have auto-scaling enabled. Selecting multi-zone will not meet the objective of auto-healing failed VMs in all cases. You would also need to create/assign a health check.

> C. In the Instance Template, add the label ‘health-check’.

This is not a possible answer. Specifying a label for an Instance Template means that the label will be applied to each instance that is created. This does nothing for health checks. This is a trick answer.

> D. In the Instance Template, add a startup script that sends a
>   heartbeat to the metadata server.

This is not a possible answer. The metadata server does not provide health check features.

**Drumroll Please ....**

Therefore the best answer is A in my opinion. A is the only answer that actually does a health check.

B is a trick answer that I think will fool many people.

The best answer is a combination of A and B plus auto-scaling, but that is not an option for this question.